# Replace spaces with underscores only when within quotes

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I need to replace all spaces which exist within quotes. 
I have several columns yet only one column has quoted output containing spaces which is throwing off my columns when using `column -t`

```
"UDP netprobe"
"ACL allow"
"ACL deny"

"UDP_netprobe"
"ACL_allow"
"ACL_deny"
```

Comment: the columns are delimited with what character? by default `column` is using whitespaces as delimiter of the input file, you can change it with `-s 'delimiter'` (where _delimiter_ is a set of characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a proper CSV parser would be recommended. In this simple case, awk will do: use double quote as the field separator character, and:

```
awk -F '"' -v OFS='"' '{
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2)
        gsub(/[[:blank:]]/, "_", $i)
    print
}' <<END
first "UDP netprobe" hello
second "ACL allow" friendly "oops, another quoted field"
third "ACL deny" world
END
```

```
first "UDP_netprobe" hello
second "ACL_allow" friendly "oops,_another_quoted_field"
third "ACL_deny" world
```

For the one-liner fans:

```
awk -F\" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2)gsub(/[[:blank:]]/,"_",$i)}1' OFS=\" file
```

Comment: | awk -F'"' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)if(i%2==0)gsub(" ","_",$i);}1' OFS="" worked the same way. THANK YOU!!

Comment: sure, but there's no need for the extra test if you know you only want every 2nd field.

Answer (score 4):

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's{".*?"}{$& =~ y/ /_/r}ge' file
```

Answer (score 4):

With sed

```
sed -E ':A;s/("[^ "]+) ([^"]*")/\1_\2/;tA' infile
```

Comment: This is the answer

Comment: You are genius! To those who wonder: `:A` defines a label which can be used in "goto" statements. `tA` goes back to the :A label if substitution (`s`) was successful.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/\("[^"]\+\) \([^"]\+"\)/\1_\2/g' file
```

The regex looks for word within double, and the command replaces space with underscore.

Comment: Did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/\(\"[^" ]*\) \([^"]*\"\)/\1_\2/g' file
```

Caveat: it only works with a single space between a pair of double quotes.